TYPO3 error while updating site configuration in version 11
after the update process from TYPO3 v10 to v11 i get following error when accessing any site configuration in the backend:
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1439298496: Unknown special value languages for field forceLanguage of table site | UnexpectedValueException thrown in file /Volumes/Works/MAMP_Projects/GDF2025/site/xxxxx/zzzzzz/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/FormDataProvider/AbstractItemProvider.php in line 229
I don´t understand the message, e.g. there is no table called site in any TYPO3 installation. The message also appears when i create a new site configuration.
I use PHP 8.3.9 (I tried other branches of PHP as well), MySQL 5.7 and TYPO3 11.5.0.

Hm. Did you clear all caches (especially TCA cache comes to mind) and ran the DB compare tool? Any custom extensiojs involved, maybe grep their TCA for "forceLanguage"? Did you create a site config (filesystem?)

Yes, i have done all those steps without success.

TYPO3 SiteConfiguration uses pseudo TCA, or better to say, a
restricted subset of usual TCA to provide form engine based
backend module editing cababilities.
Thus, TCA/FormEngine uses table as it does not know that it
sources site configuration stuff from files instead of database
tables.
Taking the rest of the error message, I assume that you have a
forceLanguage:

key in one of the site configuration yaml fields, which does not have a valid pseudo tca for it.
Did you used 3rd party extensions adding custom configuration to the
site configuation tca and removed it during the update ? Eventually,
that extension has an update.
If that was done by a custom local project extension or sitepackage
extension, ensure that the syntax is still correct and loaded.
Otherwise, search for that file in the site-configuration files manually.

when accessing any site configuration in the backend:

That helps you to look directly into that specific site which is crushing
and remove the invalid value - or determine which has defined that pseudo
code.
Just to be sure, did you executed all TYPO3 upgrade wizards already ?
TYPO3 v11 does not defines that SiteConfiguration field at all, so it must be something custom or introduced by a 3rd party extension. Check all installed extension if a Configuration/SiteConfiguration folder exists
with some content - and lookup which defines the forceLanguage field.
Reading the message again, it seams that not the key forceLanguages is the issue, but the value:
forceLanguages: language

or similar. Comment that out, clear all caches and you should be able to open the site config in the backend (except there are further error based of the extending)

I tried all those steps to no avail. The was no problem with the site configuration yaml files.  But checking the sitepackage was a good tip. It seems like the sitepackage was not downwards compatible, i used my latest version (12). After continuing to upgrade to TYPO3 12 all problems were gone. I never came across this issue since i usually upgrade straight away to versions 12 (or the latest available), but with this particular installation i had to upgrade to version 11 first.
